# Javascript - element.addEventListener() returns "Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: javascript, html, css

For context, I am trying to code a memory game where you have to pair two of the same colored circles until the whole board is complete. I've called it Match-Two. Here is the code that I'll reference from:

```
class Circle {
    constructor(element, circleColor){
        this.elem = element;
        this.color = circleColor;
    }
}
var frequency = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var num; 
var hue = new Array(8);
var circle = new Array(16);

hue[0] = "#0039ff";
hue[1] = "#ff0000";
hue[2] = "#43ff00";
hue[3] = "#fffa00";
hue[4] = "#7405b5";
hue[5] = "#ff9d00";
hue[6] = "#ff00c3";
hue[7] = "#00fff6";

onload = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        circle[i] = new Circle(document.getElementById("circle" + i));
        while(circle[i].color === undefined){
            num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
            if(frequency[num] != 2){
                frequency[num]++;
                circle[i].color = hue[num];   
                circle[i].elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
                    main(circle[i])
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
function main(circle){
    circle.elem.style.backgroundColor = circle.color;
}
```

So in this code I create a class of Circle and I create an array of Circle objects which is identified as 'circle'. When the page is loaded, I give each circle object an element reference from my html document (There are 16 circles and they each have an id of circle0, circle1, circle2.. etc. Then there's a small algorithm to ensure there are only two of each color in the matrix so they all have a matching pair. In each iteration of the for loop, I add an event listener to each circle. If the circle is clicked, I want it to change to its color which is stored in color[i].color. However, when I click the circles all it returns is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elem' of undefined
at main (script.js:39)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (script.js:31)
```

Which is referencing:

```
circle.elem.style.backgroundColor = circle.color;
```

So I put some console.log() functions in to see what was going on:

```
if(frequency[num] != 2){
    frequency[num]++;
    circle[i].color = hue[num];   
    console.log(circle[i].elem);
    console.log(circle[i].color);
    circle[i].elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
        main(circle[i])
    });
}
```

And this spits out exactly what I expect:

```
script.js:31 #ff9d00
script.js:30 div data-brackets-id=​"11" class=​"circle" id=​"circle1" /div
script.js:31 #ff9d00
script.js:30 div data-brackets-id=​"12" class=​"circle" id=​"circle2" /div
script.js:31 #0039ff
script.js:30 div data-brackets-id=​"13" class=​"circle" id=​"circle3" /div
script.js:31 #0039ff
```

So it returns the element reference and the color of the circle. So then I try putting the "circle[i].elem.style.backgroundColor = circle[i].color" into the event listener and I get the same issue as before...

```
if(frequency[num] != 2){
    frequency[num]++;
    circle[i].color = hue[num];   
    console.log(circle[i].elem);
    console.log(circle[i].color);
    circle[i].elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
        circle[i].elem.style.backgroundColor = circle[i].color
    });
}
```

[Circles without their colors. The console log statements are on the right-hand side with their specific colors as well...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMshQ.png)

So I gave up and decided to write that exact line of code outside the event listener to see if that works, and it changed all the circle's colors to their specific color...

```
if(frequency[num] != 2){
    frequency[num]++;
    circle[i].color = hue[num];   
    console.log(circle[i].elem);
    console.log(circle[i].color);
    circle[i].elem.style.backgroundColor = circle[i].color;
    circle[i].elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
        circle[i].elem.style.backgroundColor = circle[i].color
    });
}
```

[The circles with their specific colors...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxGUX.png)

There is some problem the event listener not being able to pass the object of a Circle or something... I don't know please help :(

Comment: Can you generate this error message again and then copy the line of code that it points to (which was line 39 at some point in the past) and paste it in your question so we can see which code is triggering the error?
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elem' of undefined at main (script.js:39)`

Comment: Try using `let i = 0` instead of `var i = 0` in your for loop declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem boils down to the way JS treats `var` variables - they sort of "leak" into the global scope.

Consider the event listener that you've attached:

```
circle[i].elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
  main(circle[i])
});
```

So, whenever the listener gets triggered, it calls `main()` function and passes `circle[i]` into it. But since `i` is the variable that's leaked outside of the supposed scope, it always has the value of `16` - the value assigned to it during the last iteration of the `for` loop. That's why the `main()` function tries to access a `style` property of `undefined` - it's the value of `circle[16]` that was passed into it.

Here's a couple of ways to fix it:

### If you can use ES6 `let` variables:

Use `let i` instead of `var i` in your `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  //...
}
```

### If not, a classic way with function closure:

```
function createListener(j) {
  return function () {
    main(circle[j])
  }
}
// and use it in your 'for' loop later:
circle[i].elem.addEventListener('click', createListener(i));
```

Here's a useful topic that provides more techniques to avoid this: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)